# JavaScript game not working, freezes after initialization

Tags: javascript, oop, game-engine

I have the following problem: I'am trying to make a simple game in JavaScript. The idea of the game is to have a canvas, a ball bouncing inside and small pad going left to right to hit the ball. I've done it like this, and it works fine:

```
var canvasBg;
var contextBg;

var canvasBall;
var contextBall;


function Drawable() {

    this.initialize = function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    this.draw = function() {

    };
}

function Ball() {

    var dx = 2;
    var dy = 2;

    var radius = 5;

    this.draw = function() {

        contextBall.beginPath();
        contextBall.clearRect(0,0,canvasBall.width,canvasBall.height);
        contextBall.closePath();

        contextBall.beginPath();
        contextBall.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
        contextBall.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        contextBall.closePath();
        contextBall.fill();

        // the code seems to stop here
        if(this.x<0 || this.x>300)
            dx = -dx;
        if(this.y<0 || this.y>150)
            dy = -dy;

        if((this.x+radius)>pad.x && (this.x-radius)<(pad.x+50) && (this.y+radius)>pad.y && (this.y-radius)<(pad.y+10)) {
            dy = -dy;
        } 

        if(this.y>(pad.y-2) && this.y<(pad.y+12) && (this.x+radius)>pad.x && (this.x-radius)<(pad.x+50)) {
            dx = -dx;
        }

        this.x += dx;
        this.y += dy;
    };

}

Ball.prototype = new Drawable();

KEY_CODES = {

    37: 'left',
    39: 'right',
};

KEY_STATUS = {};

for (code in KEY_CODES) {

    KEY_STATUS[ KEY_CODES[ code ]] = false;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
    }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
        if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
    }
};

function Pad() {

    var hSpeed = 5;
    this.padWidth = 50;
    this.padHeight = 10;

    this.draw = function() {

        contextBg.clearRect(0,0,canvasBg.width,canvasBg.height);
        contextBg.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        contextBg.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.padWidth,this.padHeight);

    };

    this.move = function() {
        if(KEY_STATUS.left || KEY_STATUS.right) {
            contextBg.clearRect(0,0,canvasBg.width,canvasBg.height);

            if(KEY_STATUS.left) {
                this.x -= hSpeed;
            if (this.x <= 0)
                this.x = 0;
            } else if (KEY_STATUS.right) {
                this.x += hSpeed;
            if (this.x >= 300-this.padWidth)
                this.x = 300 - this.padWidth;
            }
            this.draw();
        }
    };
}

Pad.prototype = new Drawable();


function init() {

        canvasBg = document.getElementById('display');
        contextBg = this.canvasBg.getContext('2d');

        canvasBall = document.getElementById('ball');
        contextBall = this.canvasBall.getContext('2d');

        ball = new Ball();
        ball.initialize(10,10);

        pad = new Pad();
        pad.initialize(120,80);

        setInterval(function(){animate();},30);

}

function animate() {
        ball.draw();
        pad.draw();
        pad.move();
};
```

However, I decided to try to improve my code a bit, and i made a class GamePlay:

```
var game = new GamePlay();

function Drawable() {

    this.initialize = function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    this.draw = function() {

    };
}

function Ball() {

    var dx = 2;
    var dy = 2;

    var radius = 5;

    this.draw = function() {

        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
        this.context.closePath();

        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
        this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        this.context.closePath();
        this.context.fill();



        if(this.x<0 || this.x>300)
            dx = -dx;
        if(this.y<0 || this.y>150)
            dy = -dy;

        if((this.x+radius)>pad.x && (this.x-radius)<(pad.x+50) && (this.y+radius)>pad.y && (this.y-radius)<(pad.y+10)) {
            dy = -dy;
        } 

        if(this.y>(pad.y-2) && this.y<(pad.y+12) && (this.x+radius)>pad.x && (this.x-radius)<(pad.x+50)) {
            dx = -dx;
        }


        this.x += dx;
        this.y += dy;
    };

}

Ball.prototype = new Drawable();

KEY_CODES = {

    37: 'left',
    39: 'right',
};

KEY_STATUS = {};

for (code in KEY_CODES) {

    KEY_STATUS[ KEY_CODES[ code ]] = false;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
    }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
        if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
    }
};

function Pad() {

    var hSpeed = 5;
    this.padWidth = 50;
    this.padHeight = 10;

    this.draw = function() {

        this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
        this.context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        this.context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.padWidth,this.padHeight);

    };

    this.move = function() {
        if(KEY_STATUS.left || KEY_STATUS.right) {
            this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);

            if(KEY_STATUS.left) {
                this.x -= hSpeed;
            if (this.x <= 0)
                this.x = 0;
            } else if (KEY_STATUS.right) {
                this.x += hSpeed;
            if (this.x >= 300-this.padWidth)
                this.x = 300 - this.padWidth;
            }
            this.draw();
        }
    };
}

Pad.prototype = new Drawable();

function GamePlay() {

    var ball;
    var pad;

    this.setUpGame = function() {

        this.canvasBg = document.getElementById('display');
        this.contextBg = this.canvasBg.getContext('2d');

        this.canvasBall = document.getElementById('ball');
        this.contextBall = this.canvasBall.getContext('2d');

        Ball.prototype.canvas = this.canvasBall;
        Ball.prototype.context = this.contextBall;

        Pad.prototype.canvas = this.canvasBg;
        Pad.prototype.context = this.contextBg;

        ball = new Ball();
        ball.initialize(10,10);

        pad = new Pad();
        pad.initialize(120,80);

    };


    var animate = function() {
        ball.draw();
        pad.draw();
        pad.move();
    };

    this.startGame = function() {
        setInterval(function(){animate();},30);
    };

}

function init() {
    game.setUpGame();
    game.startGame();
}
```

BUT, it only draws a ball on its initializing coordinates and then seems to stop there. I tried to do some manual testing by putting alert() on certain points in code and I found out that it seems to stop in the middle of ball's draw method and skips calling pad.draw() and pad.move() in animate(). I don't know what is wrong, my guess that is something with prototypes. I am new to JavaScript and this prototype-based OOP is still a bit confusing to me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I use Aptana Studio and the console stays clean. But I don't get the desired results in my html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried code and found next problems:

1. function `init` - hope it is called after html is fully loaded
2. `Ball.draw` function refers object `pad`, which is not defined in its context, use `game.pad`
3. `var animate = function` creates local "private" variable, change it to `this.animate = function`
4. in setInterval call proper function `setInterval(function(){game.animate();},30);`
5. `var game = new GamePlay();` is called before `GamePlay` is defined, move this string below

after these changes it works without errors in console

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made those corrections but i still I get the same result in html. I use <script src="game_engine/game.js"></script> between head tags and <body onload="init()">. Is that the right way to load the script.

Comment: @somi then I really suggest you to use browser's developer tools and debug code, also check 5th item I've added

Comment: Finally I've made it! The problem was in 2nd item. Now I have a public method to access the pad and it works as I wanted. Your answer really helped me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of your miss-use of paths in your draw method.

First, you don't need to wrap `.clearRect` with `.beginPath` and `.closePath`.

Second, and what is likely causing your script to error is that you are using `.fill` after `.closePath`when you draw the circle. `.fill` should be used before `.closePath` and actually after using `.fill` you don't need to use `.closePath` as it will already close your path for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have made corrections you suggested but I still get the same results.